In Python, can I round all printed floats with a single command?
I am working with a Python script that prints many floating point numbers.  Within each print command, I use round(x, 3) to round the printed number x to 3 decimal places before printing.  Here is a simplified example:
x1 = 1.61803398875
print('x1 = ' + str(round(x1, 3)))  # x1 = 1.618
x2 = x1**2
print('x2 = ' + str(round(x2, 3)))  # x2 = 2.618
x3 = 1/(x2-1)
print('x3 = ' + str(round(x3, 3)))  # x3 = 0.618

The actual code contains hundreds of these print commands.  Is there a more efficient way to perform the rounding part of this script?  For example, is there a single overarching command that will round all printed floats to a given precision, as there is for numpy and pandas variables?
I am looking for a solution that does not involve moving or combining the print commands or converting the printed variables to numpy and pandas variables before printing.

Given the amount of repetition, why not just write a function printRounded(x) to do it?

Use an f-string with formatting.

would you be okay writing another function and calling that?

I don't think there's any way to customize the default formatting of numbers.

you can overwrite builtins to monkeypatch print but idk if worth

print(f'x1 = {x1:.3f}') # x1 = 1.618 is at least a lot easier to write than str(round(...)) IMO, but I'm not sure if that gets you as far as you want.

Using f-strings is a much easier way to specify rounding in string representations of numbers:
x1 = 1.61803398875
print(f'x1 = {x1:.3f}')  # x1 = 1.618
x2 = x1**2
print(f'x2 = {x2:.3f}')  # x2 = 2.618
x3 = 1/(x2-1)
print(f'x3 = {x3:.3f}')  # x3 = 0.618

but you do still need to repeat the .3f part each time.
If you wanted to DRY as much as possible, you could write a wrapper:
def print_var(var: str, val: float) -> None:
    print(f'{var} = {val:.3f}')


x1 = 1.61803398875
print_var('x1', x1)  # x1 = 1.618
x2 = x1**2
print_var('x2', x2)  # x2 = 2.618
x3 = 1/(x2-1)
print_var('x3', x3)  # x3 = 0.618

or you could redefine print (I wouldn't recommend this one, personally):
import builtins

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    rounded_args = [
        f'{arg:.3f}' if isinstance(arg, float) else arg
        for arg in args
    ]
    builtins.print(*rounded_args, **kwargs)


x1 = 1.61803398875
print('x1 = ', x1)  # x1 = 1.618
x2 = x1**2
print('x2 = ', x2)  # x2 = 2.618
x3 = 1/(x2-1)
print('x3 = ', x3)  # x3 = 0.618

